# Is there a word for fearing oneself?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

My brother exhibits this strange behaviour. He once saw his shadow on the wall and screamed in alarm thinking it was a ghost. Another day, when his collar flaps fluttered in the wind, he became nervous that someone was lurking behind him.

Under cases of extreme panic, he develops an abnormal fear of his own making. Is there a name for this? Could we call this autophobia?

Comment: I think this is Off Topic General Reference. A typical online definition for *autophobia* is [a fear of being alone or of one's self](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/autophobia)

Comment: What  you described is more than fear of himself. "Nervous that someone was lurking behind him" sounds like paranoia. Taking your description as a whole, it sounds like anxiety disorder (or "generalized anxiety disorder"). I suggest that you edit your subject or your question to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-phobia

It means both a fear of self or fear of being alone.